# UDP packet order in Linux if limited to one-core

Tags: linux, networking, udp

Hi I'm trying to do an experiment based on UDP.

I want to utilize RSS and IRQ to make all UDP packets of my application processed in one-core. To be more specific, I'll have a NIC queue, and bind the IRQ to a CPU-core.

I'm wondering if I can assume that the order of processing UDP packets in XDP(eBPF kernel hook) and that order in user-space is the same? Or is there a possible way to verify this.

My opinion is that since only one-core processes the packets, there is no concurrency, then every-thing should be in order.

Comment: No. You cannot assume UDP packet delivery or uniqueness or ordering.

Comment: But I'm considering the order that one-CPU-core polls packet from one NIC queue. Since there is only one core, after this polling order, the earlier polled out packet should precede later packets(maybe just like in TCP).

Comment: I'm not considering the underlying network. The comparison is between the order in Kernel and the order in user-space, assuming all UDP packets are polled from one NIC queue.